# Display an error if row already exists in insert data into SQL Server database using vb 2010

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I have written a program to connect to SQL Server and insert data.

When I insert data into database with same `StrUserID` in SQL Server, it inserted data a second time, without an error Like that image in sql..

[image]

I need to ensure that data is only inserted into the database once, and if a row with the same `StrUserID` already exists, I need to display a message telling him "such a user name already exists".

Like that photo...

[image]

This is my code to insert data into database..

```
Query = "insert into TB_User (StrUserID,password)  Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
```

My second problem: when user create/insert data into sql I need to make password row change to MD5 not a normal password like the first photo in the first row...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form2
    Public mysqlconn As SqlConnection
    Public command As SqlCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mysqlconn = New SqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=SRO_VT_ACCOUNT;user id=sa;password=123"
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into TB_User (StrUserID,password)  Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
            command = New SqlCommand(Query, mysqlconn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
            mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or My SQL???

Comment: You need to parameterize your queries immediately if not sooner. What you have here is a textbook example of sql injection.

Comment: Why should the user name be unique?  Look at [how many SO users have a name of "Steve"](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=week&search=steve)  Also, use SQL paramters - test a name of `D'Angleo` to see why, also an unsalted MD5 hash is fairly weak.

Comment: You also need to stop storing passwords in clear text in your database. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: To solve the question you are asking you need to look at using EXISTS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: Why do you not have a unique constraint on the column where you want unique values? I see a lot of design issues in a very small amount of detail being shared.

Comment: iam using a MYsql....

Answer (score 0):

1 Build a unique constraint and handle the appropriate exception:

```
ALTER TABLE TB_User ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_USER_ID UNIQUE (StrUserID)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024(v=sql.120).aspx

2 Try `HASBYTES` function:

```
insert ...
values (:UserID, HASHBYTES('MD5', pwd))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174415(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: this is will work with me with my above codes?.. iam usinq sql2008 and vb2010 ?

Comment: @AbdelazizOmar yes it does, just input values are limited to 8000 bytes.

Comment: @krtek .. How like that? : insert 800 bytes (:UserID, HASHBYTES('MD5', pwd) ?? or what?

Comment: @AbdelazizOmar lol nope, standard `insert into` command - google how to insert into table, and then `hashbytes('MD5', 'YOUR STRING HERE')`